What sci-fi show was Ernie watching in the show My Three Sons?
Many years ago, I saw an episode of My Three Sons which referred to a science fiction TV show.  For some reason, I've always remembered it as being a reference to Lost in Space.
I've never seen Lost in Space, so I have no idea whether the reference was really to that series, or if it were maybe just a joke inspired by that series.
The scene in My Three Sons went like this:
Ernie is watching TV, the father (played by Fred MacMurray) walks into the living room.  He asks Ernie why he's watching the TV when it is turned off.
Ernie answers that he's watching an episode of {unknown scifi series.}  The ship is trapped in a black hole, so of course there's no light, which is why the picture on the TV is completely black.

Was this a reference to a real scifi TV show?
If it was real, which episode of the series was it?


Which episode of My Three Sons was this?

It was one shortly after Ernie was adopted.  I couldn't find a list of episodes detailed enough for this incident to be described.

The term "black hole" wasn't coined until 1967.

@OrganicMarble That is the traditional story, but it is incorrect. From what I can tell it dates back to at least December 1963.

@Ziggy https://www.amnh.org/learn-teach/curriculum-collections/cosmic-horizons-book/john-michell-black-holes I'll go with AMNH unless you've got something better.

In My Three Sons Season 7 Episode 18, "TV or Not TV", at about 3 minutes into the episode, Ernie wants to watch the fictional program "Blast Off".

I can't miss "Blast Off"! ... Last week the rocket reactor power on the Galaxy Queen had lost its heterogeneity and were drifting into a time warp.
[later]
You're not on the channel.
Sure I am! This is it.
There's nothing on the screen.
Sure there is!
How come I don't see anything?
You're not supposed to! This is what happens when you get caught in a time warp. The whole crew ended up invisible!

The episode can be streamed on Amazon Prime.

That sounds like it.  I don't have Prime, so I'll see if I can find it somewhere else.

Ah, time warp, not black hole. Makes sense.

I found the season 7 episode 18 on YouTube.  That is indeed the episode I had in mind.  I got some things wrong, but the identification is correct. Blast Off was the show.  Like all the other shows and movies mentioned in the episode, Blast Off was made up just for the episode.  It was a time warp rather than a black hole.

Ernie was adopted in an episode on September 30, 1965; Lost in Space premiered in that same season (on September 15). So far as I can tell, the original Lost in Space series never featured a black hole.
I suspect that writers for "My Three Sons" would have been more familiar with 1950s TV SF like Space Patrol and others, than with what was then current TV. If I find an old episode of one of those with a black hole, I'll update to add that info
